# Angularjs : - tree - table combination.

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My current task involves creating a dash board which is uses tree structure and table.

My code is available in the plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/Fe1LAcc8iNP03dImlWUn?p=preview

I want to know how achieve the below points in the above plunker.

1) If the parent is checked then all its children should get checked.
For example, if Name is  checked then all its children repo1,repo8 and repo7 should get checked automatically. Similarly all the children of repo1,repo7 and repo8.

2) If I manually check the children of say repo1 then repo1 also should get checked. If even one child is un checked then repo1 should get unchecked too.

Help on this is appreciated.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body data-ng-app="testApp" data-ng-controller="treeTable">

<hr>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" data-ng-click="save()">SaveFilter</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-Default" data-dismiss="modal" data-ng-click="delete()">Delete</button>
<div  class="row">
<div class="col-md-9">
<div style=" margin-left:50px;" class="tableheight">
  <table class="table-nested ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <!-- <th >
          <input data-ng-checked="(list | selected).length == list.length" data-ng-click="toggleAllCheckboxes($event)" type="checkbox" />
        </th> -->

        <th>
        Repository
        </th>
        <th >
          Version
        </th>
        <th >
          Size
        </th>
        <th >
        Modified By
        </th>
        <th >
        Labels
        </th>
        <th >
        Description
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody  style="font-size:12px"  data-ng-repeat="item in list">
    <tr >
      <td  ><button style="background-color: #fff;" class="accordion"></button>
       {{item.name}}
      </td>

      <td >
        {{item.Version}} 
      </td>
      <td >
        {{item.Size}}
      </td>
      <td >
        {{item.ModifiedBy}}
      </td>
      <td >
        {{item.Labels}}
      </td>
      <td >
        {{item.Description}}
      </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```